# How to calculate the angle between two points and rotate the third point baste on that?

Tags: c++, opencv, math

I have a set of points based on which I want to calculate the next point's location. To give you a concrete idea of what I'm exactly after, consider  the following image:

[image]

For this image, I have both eyes center points(which are shown as yellow) and I need to calculate the proper location for the green ones.

[image]

If the head was not tilted it would be easy as all the points lie on the same straight line. However, without taking the angle, I can't approximate the new points accurately. Suppose the landmarks are as follows:

```
left_eye = {X=128,Y=121}
right_eye = {X=188,Y=81}
```

Now for a straight face, I'd do something like this:

```
auto distance = (right_eye_x - left_eye_x) / 4;
auto left_eye_left_corner = left_eye_x - distance;
auto left_eye_right_corner = left_eye_x + distance;
auto right_eye_left_corner = right_eye_x - distance;
auto right_eye_right_corner = right_eye_x + distance;
```

and for the `Y`s I'd use the respective eye's Y location.

However, when the head is tilted, I obviously can't use this method. So I need to calculate the angle between the eyes and then somehow incorporate this into the Y's calculation (and possibly also X's calculation).  This is where I'm stuck.

If my memory serves me right, the angle could be calculated like this `tan = (Y/X)`, and thus to get the actual angle(theta) we would use `atan`. (also explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1201337/finding-the-angle-between-two-points))

[image]

Now for the angle, I'd write :

```cpp
auto deltaY = abs(right_eye_Y - left_eye_Y);
auto deltaX = abs(right_eye_X - left_eye_X);
auto angle = atan2(deltaY, deltaX);
```

Now for getting the new locations we apply the angle :

```
new_x = distance * cos(angle) 
new_y = distance * sin(angle)
```

and since we want this not to be relative to the `(0,0)` we offset this with a point(x0,y0). I presume this to be `left_eye`'s and `right_eye`'s `X` and `Y` coordinates respectively.

This is where I get stuck. For one, unlike the `X` axis, I do not have any distance for the `Y` axis of these [green] points and therefore simply doing something like below fails miserably!

```cpp
auto left_eye_left_corner = distance * cos(angle) - left_eye_x;
auto left_eye_left_corner_y = left_eye_y * sin(angle);
auto left_eye_right_corner = distance * cos(angle) + left_eye_x;
auto left_eye_right_corner_y = left_eye_y * sin(angle);

auto right_eye_left_corner = distance * cos(angle) - right_eye_x;
auto right_eye_left_corner_y = right_eye_y * sin(angle);
auto right_eye_right_corner = distance * cos(angle) + right_eye_x;
auto right_eye_right_corner_y = right_eye_y * sin(angle);
```

How should I be going about this?

Comment: Good rule of thumb. If your calculation involves `atan2` to calculate an angle and then `sin` and `cos` on that same angle, then you're missing a simplification of the process that could work out the same values using only proportions (or similar triangles, or vector arithmetic or whatever you want to call it)

Comment: @john thanks a lot. that's a great tip to remember. I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're making this far too complicated.

Take the two points:

```
L = {X=128,Y=121}
R = {X=188,Y=81}
```

And do a little vector arithmetic:

```
D  = (R-L)/4
LL = L-D
LR = L+D
RL = R-D
RR = R+D
```

And you're done.

More pedantically (if you don't like vector arithmetic, or don't want to define a `Point` class),

```
Dx  = (Rx-Lx)/4
LLx = Lx-Dx
...
```

and so on, and the same for the y's.